# PHP get cell content

Tags: php, cell, file-get-contents, explode

I want to retrieve with PHP the contents of a **table cell** to another file. With this code, I retrieve the contents of **all** cells of the **row**.

```
$url = 'folder/myPage.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode('<tr id="foo">' , $content );
$second_step = explode('</tr>' , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

How to retrieve a particular cell ? (the second, for example...)

```
$url = 'folder/myPage.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

//Ugly Code !...doesn't work !

$first_step = explode('<tr id="foo"><td[1]' , $content );
$second_step = explode('</td></tr>' , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Thanks.Nicolas.

Comment: You should not use PHP to inspect a DOM document, but in any case.. if you do then use a [library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Comment: I will try. Thanks.

Comment: If it's not PHP, it's AJAX ? Jquery ?

Comment: Its done by not having the need to do it in the first place, `myPage.php` is located on the same server no? look at the code that generates that table and see what you need to do by fetching that data you're looking for. PHP generates HTML and functions like `file_get_contents()` can be used to fetch a JSON, RRS, etc response, specific data PHP can use. Downloading a compete HTML file only to use 1% of the data is a lot of overhead.

Comment: I will "convert" my <table> in ""json" file. Thanks for your help. Nicolas.

Comment: I want to download a complete HTML because i have a lot of informations.
I said "second cell" just for example. In fact I have hundreds of cells..!

Comment: Have you checked that library?

Comment: I've found the solution ! See my post below. Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution !! the second explode with the `</td>` and not with the `</tr>` :

```
$url = 'folder/myPage.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode('<tr id="' . $ref . '">' , $content );
$second_step = explode('</td>' , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[1]; // show the content of the second cell
echo $second_step[5]; // show the content of the sixth cell
// etc...

// "$ref" is a loop with foreach in a list of elements
```

I did not want to use a library for doing that (like Simple_Html_Dom : 1800 lines of code , just to watch a file !! too heavy.)

With this solution, it's
working like a charm ! I'm happy..:-) [solved]. Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

you need to explode it also by `<td>` couse `<td>` is a 'table cell' - `<tr>` is the whole row

Comment: Two "explode" ? How to write this ?

Comment: if you really want to do this like that, than after first explode by tr you'll have array of rows, calling explode by td on every element (row) will give you an array of cells (what you need). But of course, its not a recommended way to deal with DOM in general.

Comment: I've found the solution ! See my post below. Nicolas.

Comment: why is there -1 near this entirely accurate answer to the question?